# Is there a "diminishing returns" tree search algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, trees, searching

I'm looking for an algorithm that will let me plug in a heuristic for scoring a subtree, and as the algorithm does a depth-first search, it stops when the score has:

- Already hit a threshold (minimum score)
- only changed a very small amount from child to parent

So this algorithm would be doing a fuzzy search for a "payload."

Is there an algorithm like this?

Comment: You have already described it.

Comment: Possibly related: [Infinite trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Infinite_trees). There are alternative and adaptive methods of traversing infinite trees with some sort of diminishing return, because we clearly could not traverse all of the tree.

Comment: Maybe related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_tree_search